# What is the best way to get nested JSON from database?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, api

For example i have two tables:

```
PRODUCTS (id, category_id, name);
CATEGORIES (id, name);
```

I want pass to frontend JSON like:

```
"categoryProjects": [
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "name" : "some category name",
        "projects": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Product1"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Product2"
            },
        [   
    },
    {
        "id" : 2,
        "name" : "second category name",
        "projects": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Product3"
            }
        [   
    }
]
```

My question is: What is the best way to do this? I want it to be as efficient as possible. I have simple server in php, database (mysql), and I want create API. I wonder what is the best way to do endpoint for my frontend.

Comment: have you tried anything ?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [ask].

Comment: Yes, I create endpoints to get all categories, and second one to get product by category_id. But, then on frontend I need call API many times, and I think this solution is ineffective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to do a SQL join, like so

```sql
select products.*, categories.name as category from products left join categories on products.category_id = categories.id
```

Then map the returned table to a PHP array and convert it to JSON.

```php
<?php
$sth = $pdo->query("select products.*, categories.name as category from products left join categories on products.category_id = categories.id");
$rows = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$categories = [];

foreach ($rows as $row)
{
    if (!isset($categories[$row['category_id']]))
    {
        $categories[$row['category_id']] = [
            "name" => $row['category'],
            "id" => $row['category_id'],
            "products" => []
        ];
    }

    $categories[$row['category_id']]['products'][] = [
        "id" => $row['id'],
        'name' => $row['name']
    ];
}

print json_encode($categories, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

This code will run assuming your tables were built as you described them.